# Hue Filebrowser Search is searching only in the first layer

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera, hue

I had installed Hue with the Cloudera Manager on AWS. I have uploaded some directories with few files in there. If I am on the `/user/hdfs` path, there are directories like `project1`, `project2`. If I am searching project, I get as result the projects. But if Im searching to files in the project directories like `file1`, I get no result. I have looked at config files from `hdfs`, `hue`, `solr`, but cannot find this configuration parameter. How can I fix that, so I can search deeper in the hdfs with hue filebrowser?

Answer (score 0):

Hue doesn't use solr for the file browser, it's webhdfs, which is only able to search from the current folder

Answer (score 0):

The search within the File Browser is just a filtering of the files on the current directory, not a full text search across all the directories.

Currently the top search is only about tables and documents: http://gethue.com/realtime-catalog-search-with-hue-and-apache-atlas/

In the future, it will be extended to leverage the File search of Apache Atlas.

Comment: How can I access or install apache atlas on my Hue on Cloudera Manager on aws?